# OpenSSH: Restriction on Local Port Forwarding for groups

Tags: openssh

I'm trying to restrict users who connect via ssh on a server (with OpenSSH) to do local port forwarding on certain ports only.

I've found that setting the `permitopen="address:port"` option in their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files do what I expect.

However it is not very convenient since I have to edit all existing authorized_keys files and if, in the future, I want to allow more ports, change the allowed ports,... I will have to edit them all again.

Is something similar achievable for all users in a group i.e. "allow local port forwarding only on address:port if the user belongs to this group"?

Thanks!

**EDIT>** it seems that the sshd_config file has a feature which allows this: Match. I can match an user or a group and apply some custom configs for them among which PermitOpen which I must have skipped while reading the man page for the first time.

Comment: Is using a script to do the editing of ~${username}/.ssh/authorized_keys an option ?

Comment: I would prefer to do it otherwise, but yes it is definitely the option I will choose if nothing else is possible :) I will have to improve my bash skills though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify conditional blocks in [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html) and apply directives like `PermitOpen` to restrict what users can do. The following would allow members of the `restricted` group to only tunnel connections to port 1234 on the server and port 80 on google.com

```
Match Group restricted
    PermitOpen localhost:1234 google.com:80
```

Comment: yes, that's what I noticed in my edit. Flagging it as the right answer though.